# Doubt regarding a theorem in electrostatics of ponderable media

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

Suppose I have a bunch of charge distribution that is initially there, $\rho_{f}$ denoting the free charge. The field created by this charge distribution is $E_{0}$, and let's say I have two equipotential surfaces of $E_{0}$ between which I place a linear dielectric material of dielectric permittivity $\epsilon$. I.E. Irodov says (*Basic laws of Electromagnetism*, chapter 3, page 64), one can write the net electric field created by both the bound and free charge as $E=\frac{E_{0}}{\epsilon}$, but doesn't give a proof. How does one prove this statement?

Comment: In [the Wikipedia article on capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor), we see the statement "From Gauss's law, the magnitude of the electric field between the plates is $E=\sigma/\epsilon$". Is this statement not enough?

Comment: @HEMMI I did not mention capacitors in my question. This is more general

Comment: It does explain citing the continuity of the displacement vector $\vec D$ on page 85 in my copy.

Comment: @Farcher Could you be a bit more clear? And in my edition page 85 is completely unrelated and has no mention of displacement

Comment: [Try this link](https://emineter.files.wordpress.com/2020/04/i.-e.-irodov-basic-laws-of-electromagnetism-mir-publishers-moscow-1986.pdf) for the book.